# Is the __destruct method browser dependent?

Tags: php, wordpress, destructor

I actually thought, I would understand the functionality of PHPs __destruct method. But today I stumbled over a problem:

The ngg gallery plugin for wordpress contains the nggAPI class with following method

```
function __destruct() {
    echo $this->output;
}
```

It's included via require_once

```
require_once (dirname (__FILE__) . '/xml/json.php');
exit();
```

Besides the fact, that I don't like this typical WP style of working with classes it should work. Here comes the mystery: Only when opened in Chrome, __destruct will be executed. In IE, Safari and Firefox nothing happens. I've checked it a thousand times and there is *really* no cache problem or something like that. I implemented a printOutput-Method instead of __destruct and call it at the end of the script - and it is working now.

Can this be??! Is there a reasonable explanation for this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Considering that PHP can be run without any need for a browser, something like __destruct() has no dependency on any browser

Answer (score 8):

No.

PHP runs on the server-side so it is executed before the response is send to the client. It does not matter which browser.

Comment: This is a really important distinction -- NO php methods are browser-dependant, because PHP doesn't run in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

According to the PHP manual on [constructors/destructors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) a destructor is run as soon as there are no more references to an object or as part of a shutdown sequence.

Destructors can be interrupted if the script is stopped with `exit()` inside of a destructor.

Also if you are trying to call the destructor for a parent class, you must do so manually. e.g.:

```
class Foo extends Bar
{
    public function __destruct()
    {
        parent::__destruct();
    }
}
```

Regardless, there is nothing browser specific going on, it is something in PHP.